# Truncate text and add ellipses PHP SQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, truncate

I simply want to cut my string after 150 characters and add "..." at the end. I already found some solutions here for my problem via "case when" and "left" but it keeps responding wrong syntax or gives me simply a "0" even if I try the identical code from the solutions. I am using PDO and PHP.

Here is my code:

```
$feedbackquery = "SELECT CASE WHEN length(text) >= 150 THEN left(text, 150) + '...' ELSE 
text END text FROM feedback ORDER BY RAND () LIMIT 1";

$database->query($feedbackquery);
$feedbackinput = $database->fetch();
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is the error? I'd use `concat`, not `+`; http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat.

Comment: What have you done to debug the code so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not use `+` to concatenate strings. There is a built-in `CONCAT` function:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN length(text) >= 150 THEN
        CONCAT(LEFT(text, 150), '...')
    ELSE 
        text
    END text
FROM feedback
ORDER BY RAND ()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! Works like a charm.